# Dispatch not a function React Redux Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, saga

Having trouble accessing redux dispatch method inside of props. When calling handleSubmit from the redux-form, the dispatch method returns "dispatch is not a function".

I've tried adding the action to various interfaces that I was passing into the component. The order of the parameters I'm passing into connect looks correct, as well as the syntax I'm using to pass in the action to the interfaces being passed to the component.

PropsFromDispatch contains the loginRequest action, which I'm mapping to props in the MapDispatchToProps method.

```
export interface IAppProps {
  loggingIn: any;
}

export interface IAppState {
  user: GetTokenRequest;
  submitted: boolean;
  validate: {
    emailState:string
  }

}

interface PropsFromDispatch {
  loginRequest: (username: string, password:string) => void;
}

type AllProps = IAppProps & PropsFromDispatch & ConnectedReduxProps & 
IAppState

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component<AllProps, IAppState, 
PropsFromDispatch> {
  constructor(props: AllProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = this.getInitState();

    this.handleUserNameChange = this.handleUserNameChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  private getInitState(): IAppState {


  //Where I'm getting the error
  handleSubmit(e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    if (username && password) {
       this.props.loginRequest(username, password)
       //have also tried 
       dispatch(loginRequest(username,password))
    }
  }


render() {
    const {loggingIn} = this.props
    const {username, password} = this.state;
    return (
      <Container>
        <h3>Sign In</h3>
        <Form>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label>Username</Label>
              <Input
                name="email"
                id="exampleEmail"
                placeholder="firstname.lastname"
                value={ username }

                onChange={ (e) => {this.handleUserNameChange(e)} } />
              <FormFeedback valid>
                Valid Username
              </FormFeedback>
              <FormFeedback>
                Invalid UserName
              </FormFeedback>
              <FormText>Windows Login</FormText>
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Col>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="password">Password</Label>
              <Input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                id="password"
                placeholder="********"
                value={ password }
                onChange={ (e) => this.handlePasswordChange(e) }
            />
            </FormGroup>
          </Col>
          <Button onClick={(e: any) => 
this.handleSubmit(e)}>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state: { authentication: { loggingIn: any; }; }) {
  const { loggingIn } = state.authentication;
  return {
  loggingIn
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<any>): PropsFromDispatch => 
{
  return {
    loginRequest: (username: string, password: string) => 
dispatch(loginRequest(username,password))
  }

}

const connectedLoginPage = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
(LoginPage);
export { connectedLoginPage as LoginPage };
```

Comment: 1. It might be an export issue. How are you importing the component from other modules? If you are importing the default export, you are not getting the connected component.

2. You don't have the dispatch function in your props, you need to invoke this.props.loginRequest (like I see you did in your code).

Comment: @yagiro It was the way I was exporting the LoginPage as an alias.  Once I removed the const connectedLoginPage and set the default as the connect function it began picking up the dispatch props.